# .NET Recaptcha https

Tags: asp.net, https, recaptcha

We've started using the ASP.NET recaptcha control and it works fine. but one of the requirements we have is that all outbound traffic goes over Https.

I know that recaptcha supports https, but It's not clear how to configure (or even if it is configurable)  when using the ASP.NET plugin option.

has anyone got any experience of this?

I'll expand a little on what I've found so far....

The Recaptcha package contains 3 public classes

`RecaptchaControl,
RecaptchaValidator`
and
`RecaptchaResponse`

`RecaptchaControl` is an Asp.NET control, the recaptcha specific methods on there seem to be concerning themes/look and feel.

An instance of the Validator has a RemoteIP field (which I presume would represent the verification server), but I can't a way of binding that to the control.

`RecaptchaResponse` seems to more or less represent an enum with possible responses (valid/invalid/failed to connect).

looks like the Recaptcha control intelligently selects **https** if the request was https.
I'm presuming it does the same for the validation, but its not clear from source code
http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/

```
private const string VerifyUrl = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";
private const string RECAPTCHA_SECURE_HOST = "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net";        
private const string RECAPTCHA_HOST = "http://api.recaptcha.net";
--------------------------------SNIP------------------------------------
/// <summary>
        /// This function generates challenge URL.
        /// </summary>
        private string GenerateChallengeUrl(bool noScript)
        {
            StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder.Append(Context.Request.IsSecureConnection || this.overrideSecureMode ? RECAPTCHA_SECURE_HOST : RECAPTCHA_HOST);
            urlBuilder.Append(noScript ? "/noscript?" : "/challenge?");
            urlBuilder.AppendFormat("k={0}", this.PublicKey);
            if (this.recaptchaResponse != null && this.recaptchaResponse.ErrorCode != string.Empty)
            {
                urlBuilder.AppendFormat("&error={0}", this.recaptchaResponse.ErrorCode);
            }

            return urlBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 12):

If you check out http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html it says:

> "In order to avoid getting browser
>   warnings, if you use reCAPTCHA on an
>   SSL site, you should replace
>   http://api.recaptcha.net with
>   https://api-secure.recaptcha.net."

So clearly recaptcha supports HTTPS submissions. Does the ASP.NET control have any properties you can configure the outbound URL? At worst you might need to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to examine the code and see how it's built.

Comment: thanks for that Dan, I've added some details to my question. I'll certainly revisit with reflector if needs be, but hopefully someone can save me the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

The .NET library does not require any configuration to work on HTTPS environment. It will derive from the current `HttpContext` whether the request is made from HTTPS protocol.

But, there is `RecaptchaControl.OverrideSecureMode` property that you can use just in case it doesn't work as expected. Set to `True` to force HTTPS mode.

**Update**:

I seem to have misunderstood the question. I am afraid there is no HTTPS endpoint for reCAPTCHA verification (between your server and theirs).

Comment: I was running this in a load balancer with SSL offloading so the nodes didn't know about the SSL state from the usual header. So yeah this override was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are using the reCAPTCHA plugin for .NET, and we needed to do two things to get it working over SSL in our environment.  Our dev environment does not use SSL, and our test and production environments do.

1. Set the `RecaptchaControl.OverrideSecureMode` property to true, as Adrian Godong mentioned in his original answer to this question.  This allowed the control to work locally and in dev not using SSL, and in test and prod using SSL.

   ```
   <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
       OverrideSecureMode="True"
       ID="recaptcha"
       runat="server"
       Theme="blackglass"
       />
   ```
2. When we generated the public and private keys, we specified **global** keys.  This allowed us to use recaptcha in all of our different environments (local, dev.mydomain.com, test.mydomain.com and mydomain.com) and fixed the "`input error: invalid referrer`" error.

Comment: don't thinks this answers the question to be honest.  my query is specifically about the validate request made by Recaptcha.  It will work fine whether your app is https or not (unless the firewall between you and the google servers do not permit outbound https requests, in which case it will fail).while the challenge request seems to switch to https automatically, I can't see based on the code how the validate request would do the same. particularly since the protocol "http://" is embedded in the url definition.