# recaptcha makes calls over http rather than https

Tags: java, jsp, https, recaptcha

I'm using recaptcha on my java jsp setup. I use the following code in my jsp

```
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha"%>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory"%>


<%
ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", false);
out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));
out.flush();
%>
```

However the site uses https so I'm getting an 'Only secure content is displayed' message on IE.

If I look at the source recaptcha has generated the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

How do I force recaptcha to use https and not http?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.tanesha.recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j/0.0.7/net/tanesha/recaptcha/ReCaptchaFactory.java), you need to change:

```
ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(  //...
```

with:

```
ReCaptchaFactory.newSecureReCaptcha(  //...
```

That's it!

## See also

- [.NET Recaptcha https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636809)

Comment: Thanks. That changed the http to https. It still works locally but when I host it on my ssl site it fails to load the resource from google. I'm getting document.write('Input error: Invalid referer'); Any idea why?

Comment: @user456147: sorry, not really. I don't know the library you are using. Consider asking another question?

Comment: No probs. Turns out I needed to apply for a new private and public key. Cheers.

Comment: Note: Google changed their addresses, you'll need to use 0.0.8 of the jar which can be found here http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/maven-play-plugin/net/tanesha/recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j/ rather than the 0.0.7 version linked to from Google's own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way to make it works for both secure and un-secure content

```
ReCaptcha c=null;

if(request.getScheme().equals("https"))
{

     c= ReCaptchaFactory.newSecureReCaptcha(
            Constants.RECATCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
            Constants.RECATCHA_PRIVATE_KEY, false);
}else{

     c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(
            Constants.RECATCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
            Constants.RECATCHA_PRIVATE_KEY, false);

}
```