# Recaptcha validation over HTTPS

Tags: validation, https, recaptcha

I am using reCaptcha over HTTPS. All was working fine untill we moved site to client's environment. They are running everything over HTTPS. reCaptcha control is appearing with valid challenges. But it hits the wall when validating the response. As it is checking response over HTTP and not HTTPS it is not allowed access.

I have even tried putting `OverSecureMode=true` but it is still not working.

Is there any work around to make it request validation over HTTPS?

Comment: Are you using https://api-secure.recaptcha.net? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2636903/139010

Comment: I think that was changed to google servers.

Comment: Most probably it is the issue with wrong keys. I am testing and will verify once it is closed.

Comment: Updated to new version of captcha dll and got port opened for connection. It was their firewall that was causing the issue.

Comment: I had a very similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636809/net-recaptcha-https/24376163#24376163   when you say the port was opened,  the https port or the http port.  from the code I can't see how recaptcha can validate over https  (the only reference is to  a http endpoint)